# using same addressfield for profile2 and commerce module

Tags: commerce, users, entities

I have a site with two different profiles (with different fields) where one of these are able to buy a product. In this context I want to use the same addressfield for one type in the billing information making automatic filling of a company's address.

I've tried Commerce Customer Profiles module however it seems that I am unable to merge these fields. Does anyone have some suggestions on how to use profile2 information in commerce module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Profile2** and **Commerce Customer Profiles** are different entities.

Even if the address field is the same, the data will need to be copied over somehow.

One way to do it would be with

[hook_field_attach_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_load/7)

and load in the relevant address field data there, when the field is loaded.

Keep in mind:

1. That hook can be passed multiple entities
2. Ensure the user id for both entities is identical prior to merging the data.

More info on the [Field Attach API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/group/field_attach/7)